# How get text with HTML tags from server and display it in client side with HTML markup? (using php and angularjs)

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm trying to learn web development by creating an app.
I'm using Angularjs in client side and php on server side.
I need to load content of articles from server when a user select an article.
I want do the html markup in the server side and then get the text in client side and display it. (i.e. I want to do save text as "< h1>Heading< /h1> < p>paragraph< /p>" and then transfer the text to client and display it in client.

I tried echoing the text in a php file with markup tags and then get the text through $http service in angularjs. But the browser does not seem to identify the markup tags but display the html tags with the text.

How can I achieve this?

notes2.php

```
 <?php
    $variable = <<<XYZ
                <html>
                <body>
                    <h1>Heading</h1>
                    <p> paragraph </p>
                </body>
                </html>
XYZ;

    echo $variable;
 ?>
```

getnotes.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/json_test/notes2.php").then(function(response) {
            $scope.myText = response.data;
        });
}]);
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "{{myText}}";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: please make a plunker

Comment: @ThanhTùng I have added the code which I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind-html` to bind the string as HTML if you dont have any angular binding in it in angular app. Like this:

```
// in controller
$scope.html = "< h1>Heading< /h1> < p>paragraph< /p>";

// in HTML
<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

If you have any angular binding you can use `$compile` service for binding it. `$compile` creates DOM elements with angular binding to scope. That's what you would normally use to render your DOM to have two-way binding etc. working. In most cases you don't call it manually because if you add `template` or `templateUrl` to the direcive definition object it will run `$compile` automatically.

Comment: In addition to your answer, if the html text is received from the server I had to convert into a 'trusted HTML' by using  $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlTexFromServer).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write like this inside controller's scope,
    `<script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $scope.myText;
    </script>`

Comment: <script>...</script> inside controller's scope is not working. Opening tag is not getting detected. What should I do?